# Carrierwave conditional version throwing argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

I follow the official github repository example, but when I define a condition on version method, I always get:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0):
(gem) carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:198:in `block in active_versions'
(gem) carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:192:in `active_versions'
```

Here my code:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
    storage :file

    version :thumb_75, :if => :is_user? do
        process :resize_to_fill => [75, 75]
    end

    version :thumb_87, :if => :is_question? do
        process :resize_to_fill => [87, 87]
    end

    protected
    def is_user?
        model.class.to_s == 'Photo'
    end

    protected
    def is_question?
        model.class.to_s == 'Question'
    end

end
```

If I remove the conditions it works...
Any idea about what it could be?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make `is_user?` and `is_question?` methods to accept an argument:

```
protected
def is_user?(picture)
    model.class.to_s == 'Photo'
end

protected
def is_question?(picture)
    model.class.to_s == 'Question'
end
```

Comment: its not working for me , I stopped somewhere in the middle of develpment.

Comment: They should update the docs to clarify this. It's not apparent.  Just seems curious that they include a parameter for that method.